# Cannot drag/drop vector objects from Illustrator CC to Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, windows

I recently formatted my computer and in doing so lost my preferences from my Adobe programs.

I drag and drop vector images to Photoshop constantly. After the reset, dragging images to Photoshop will not place them in my canvas. The cursors act as though it is going to work (cursor does not change to stikeout circle). I am able to copy/paste, but I lose the Vector Smart Object attribute in doing this.

I do not want to save my AI files and drag and drop the files from the explorer library into my canvas. This is a waste of time. I have explored changing UAC controls, and opening as administrator, and blah blah blah.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Windows 10/Photoshop CC/Illustrator CC

Answer (score 1):

Check if this setting is ticked:

```
Edit > Preferences > General > Always Create Smart Objects when Placing
```

[image]

Comment: This option was checked, yes. The object will not place at all though. I downloaded a previous version (Photoshop CC 2014) and the problem has resolved itself. I wonder if it's just a 2015 bug?

Answer (score -1):

Use *ctrl c* to copy the vector element from Illustrator and *ctrl v* to paste it into Photoshop on the document you are working on.

Comment: Hey Suvranu! Welcome to GD.SE! It looks like the solution you offered was already tried by the person who asked the question, but they lost the Smart Object attribute when they used copy and paste. If you have any other solutions to offer, feel free to go back and edit your question. Have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) if you need any help with the site, or ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Again, welcome! :)